# Twig, display datetime collection?

Tags: string, symfony, datetime, collections, twig

I have 2 entities, Certificate and purchase. In twig i have a table where i display each certificate in rows. I really don't get how to display the last certificate.purchase.start/end. Symfony version: 5.3.7

```
        class Certificate
    {    
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Purchase::class, mappedBy="certificate")
         */
        private $purchase;
        
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->job = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->ticket = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->purchase = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|Purchase[]
         */
        public function getPurchase(): Collection
        {
            return $this->purchase;
        }
    
        public function addPurchase(Purchase $purchase): self
        {
            if (!$this->purchase->contains($purchase)) {
                $this->purchase[] = $purchase;
                $purchase->setCertificate($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removePurchase(Purchase $purchase): self
        {
            if ($this->purchase->removeElement($purchase)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($purchase->getCertificate() === $this) {
                    $purchase->setCertificate(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

And Purchase entity:

```
class Purchase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Certificate::class, inversedBy="purchase")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $certificate;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStart(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    public function setStart(\DateTimeInterface $start): self
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    public function setEnd(\DateTimeInterface $end): self
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCertificate(): ?Certificate
    {
        return $this->certificate;
    }

    public function setCertificate(?Certificate $certificate): self
    {
        $this->certificate = $certificate;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have other collections in certificate but i easly get them in twig with __toString(). Like in the job entity i have:

```
class Job
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Certificate::class, inversedBy="job")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $certificate;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you pass in the view an object `certificate` :

```
// in your controller
return $this->render('theview.html.twig',
            array('certificate' => $certificate));
```

Now, in twig, if you want to display only the last `certificate.purchase` properties, you can use the [`last`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/last.html) filter :

```
{# set a variable containing the last purchase #}
{% set lastestPurchase = certificate.purchase|last %}
last certificate start : {{ lastestPurchase.start }}
last certificate end : {{ lastestPurchase.end }}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need to pass the whole collection in the view, you can get the last element directly in the controller :

```
// TODO : Check the return value of last(), if the collection is empty, it returns false
$lastestPurchase = $certificate->getPurchase()->last();
// ...
return $this->render('theview.html.twig',
               array('lastestPurchase' => $lastestPurchase));
```

And then, in the view :

```
last certificate start : {{ lastestPurchase.start }}
last certificate end : {{ lastestPurchase.end }}
```

Comment: thank you! your solution helped me but i had to add a little bit of code cause i had pagination over certificates:

Controller:
foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {
            $lastestPurchases[] = $certificate->getPurchase()->last();
        }

Twig:

{% for lastestPurchase in lastestPurchases %}
 {% if lastestPurchase.certificate.id == certificate.id %}
  {{lastestPurchase.end|date('d F Y')}}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}